# How to call code in a php function with a post formular?

Tags: php, html, post

I have a post form. On a button press I want to pass the contents of the input field to the PHP code which is in the function "createHash". Without function it is called. But with the function unfortunately not. Could someone help me with my problem that the code in the function is called as soon as the button is pressed? I can't leave out the function unfortunately.

P.S. my file is called Blockchain.php, which I use in the action of my form.

```
<form style="visibility:hidden;" method="post" name="myform" action="Blockchain.php">
    <input style="width:1000px" id="daten2"  name="data" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
    function createhash(){
        $alldata = $_POST["data"];
        $hash = md5($alldata);
        echo $alldata;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $hash;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Hash('$hash');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: you have to call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should format it like this:

```
<?php
            
        
function createhash(){

            $alldata = $_POST["data"];
            $hash = md5($alldata);
            echo $alldata;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $hash;
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Hash('$hash');</script>";
        }
             //Here we check if the form is submited
            if(isset($_POST['send']) {
                createhash(); //Here we call the function
            }
            ?>

<form style="visibility:hidden;" method="post" name="myform">
                        <input style="width:1000px" id="daten2"  name="data" value="">
                        <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit">
                    </form>
```

Comment: Its more understandable what are you trying to do, in your example you send the data to php script Blockchain.php but you are trying to output the data in the same page..

Comment: I was referring to the formatting not logic

Comment: Avoid to provide wrong info => **I think you should format it like this:**